# AWS Amplify - Security of Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In the example below from amplify, we have to provide a few bits of configuration to allow a Javascript client to connect to Cognito.  My assumption is that it is ok to have this data in plaintext on the client.

However, on some articles it is suggested that this is not the case and I've not found anything on the official AWS sites nor the amplify site on what is considered best practice in this regard.

What is the best way to handle this config on the client if doing JS-only (I.e. no back-end involved) authentication?

```js
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', 
        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', 
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its totally fine to have this in your client side configuration. In fact its essential.

There is no secret information in the IDs, they are simply references. Its no different to exposing your API endpoints, it has to be done.

Your client has to connect to your Cognito instance. You could probably come up with some complex way of obscuring the properties by pulling them out of an online store at runtime, but your client will still ultimately expose the properties. Plus your user wouldn't be authenticated at that point so you couldn't even protect the online store.

Additionally your properties are not really mutable. It only takes one instance of exposing the properties (e.g a developer posting them, or just telling someone) and they are irreversibly lost. Trying to hide them is a losing game.

I suggest creating a backend service simply to obscure the client interaction with Cognito is an anti-pattern.

AWS provide a number of security features out-of-the-box, including account locking on incorrect password use, and blocking calls from IPs that make too many calls in a short space of time. I believe AWS services are also behind DDOS protection (see CloudFront). If someone takes your properties and tries to attack you, through account brute forcing or DDOS, they are going to have a tough time achieving anything.

Comment: Although a third party could in theory use your application's user pool to store the users of that third party's application, are there any ways to prevent that?

Comment: Urls authorized to start a connection with Cognito are defined in the Cognito configuration.